# What is the Catholic teaching on technology and faith?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism, technology

We were asked this question in class today and I find it fascinating: Should our actions as scientists or engineers in the creation of our story be guided by our faith? I would like to hear what the Catholic Church teaches about this.

Comment: The best book I've seen on this subject is _[Between science and religion: The engagement of Catholic intellectuals with science and technology in the twentieth century](https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/659563600)_ (2009) by Phillip M. Thompson.

Answer (score 12):

Catholic Church believes that Faith does not contradict science.

> Though faith is above reason, there can never be any real discrepancy between faith and reason. Since the same God who reveals mysteries and infuses faith has bestowed the light of reason on the human mind, God cannot deny himself, nor can truth ever contradict truth. Consequently, methodical research in all branches of knowledge, provided it is carried out in a truly scientific manner and does not override moral laws, can never conflict with the faith, because the things of the world and the things of faith derive from the same God. The humble and persevering investigator of the secrets of nature is being led, as it were, by the hand of God in spite of himself, for it is God, the conserver of all things, who made them what they are."- CCC 159

*Guided by our faith* does not mean if Science disagrees with Faith we should throw science away. It means that the ethical part of Science should be always guided by faith.

For example just because we have technology that finds out a Human fetus has some disability, we cannot use technology to murder that baby. You may also know that the theory of evolution in wrong hands gave rise to eugenics. Science cannot or does not have any explanation on why these are Good or Bad, Right or Wrong. Only Faith does.

Comment: *Good or Bad* better Good or Evil?